# QGIS - Lookup elevation or slope from geoTIFF from a series of lat/lon values

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, elevation, slope

I have a geoTIFF file (pretty large) covering a good chunk of Spain around Almeria. I got it from the EU-DEM v1.1 data (25m resolution), freely available in which I have a route in lat/long and I want to look up the elevation values at each point or the surface-slope between points, but elevation might be easier.

So far,

1. loaded the geoTiff in.
2. figured out how to add a new layer that can be pointed.
3. installed the point sampling tool and I found a GDAL function called slope that made a slope layer.

But I have no idea how I get QGIS to load in my sample lat/long points? and if that would even work as I see the coordinate system in the bar across the bottom seems to show pixel X, Y.

Comment: To extract the elevation value from raster at the sampling vector points, SAGA **Add raster values to points** (`Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector <-> raster`) will be useful. However, for your ultimate goal, I recommend to investigate **Profile** tools such as **qProf** plugin. Slope layer (e.g. GDAL-slope) would not give you the slope along your route (i.e. `directional slope`).

Comment: Are your lat/long points in a csv file or an excel table or similar?

Comment: Can be either, so whatever is easiest to work with. I can also have regular and very fine data (i.e. we recorded lat/lon position at 10Hz, but also downsample to 1).

Comment: I can also get them into a GPX file too.

Comment: Okay, I was able to load a gpx file in and I can see my route on the map as points and also as a line. I cannot get SAGA Add raster values to points to work. It said the layer was not generated correctly.

Comment: oooo I think I got it to work. I used qProf (as suggested). Loaded my DEM .TIF, loaded the route from gpx as a line and then asked for directional slope topographic calculation and it appears to produce something that looks sensible! thanks guys!

Comment: Ok, new issue... I have 5500 points. When I run it through qProf...its spitting out over 7000 points. When I compare the altitudes, the profile shapes are the same, but the one from qProf looks like its been stretched over a longer period. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: wait no...figured that out too. Its spitting out distance vs slope data, so when I compare to time data its all wrong.